# azure keyvault and azure identity coexisting

Tags: python, azure, installation, pip, identity

Looking at a project build where we are resolving some issues. Note this was a functional project, built by someone else but we had to migrate this. For authentication, this developer has both

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
```

However after a pip install of azure.identity, azure keyvault is not found and after a pip install of azure key vault azure.identity is not found.. aka module not found error.

Is this a known issue? At this point avoiding changes to code, but resolving libraries on the installation. Any suggestions?

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/keyvault-secrets-readme?view=azure-python, Installing one package should not remove other one. Just try pip install azure-keyvault-secrets azure-identity

Comment: I see both installed in site packages. However, azure.identity module is not found. not sure why the developer had azure.identity and not azure_identity. So installing both simultaneously worked. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @sweez, glad to hear that! That could be posted as answer.  I just help you post it that others can learn from you. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @venkat and we're glad to hear that the issue is resolved:

- "I see both installed in site packages. However, azure.identity module
  is not found. not sure why the developer had azure.identity and not
  azure_identity. So installing both simultaneously worked."

I help you post it and this can be beneficial to other community members.